# create a field where you put the ending of a url, click submit and it adds it to the already coded parent url

Tags: html

I'm trying to add a value to the end of a url that's already preset.

So for example a user would type "helloworld" into an input box, press submit and they would be taken to:

```
https://exxample.com/helloworld
```

Can I do this in HTML?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried the below answers by copying from "Function" or "Document" right down to the end of the codes but its not working right. either the top half of the code shows on the webiste  above the search box and or the submit buttion does not trigger a new page to load.

Comment: Okay then provide your current code (update the original question with what you have now)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this

It will go to

https://yoursite.com/portraits/

if you type `portraits` and hit enter

```js
document.getElementById("urlForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const val = document.getElementById("url").value.trim(); 
  const newUrl = "https://example.com/"+val+"/";
  location=newUrl;
})
```

```html
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="text" id="url" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Here is how the code should look at your site

```html
<form id="urlForm">
  <input type="text" id="url" value="" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script>
document.getElementById("urlForm").addEventListener("submit",function(e) {
  e.preventDefault()
  const val = document.getElementById("url").value.trim(); 
  const newUrl = "https://example.com/"+val+"/";
  location=newUrl;
})
</script>
```

Comment: thanks this one is showing the top part in clear text on the site and when entered it is only adding the text to the url path but not actually submitting to the page. its also adding a "?" which is also going to interfere with the URL

Comment: its really weird, if i run it in here it looks like it tries to go to the site ok but if i copy the code into my website with the HTML widget, the top part of the code shows and now hitting enter does nothing. also i need a submit button under the field  :) thanks heaps!

Comment: I added a submit. It is not needed when you only have one field

Comment: lc   photo.com.au/sandbox.  (just remove the space and you can see what i mean

Comment: You need to wrap the code in `<script></script>` tags

Comment: @LoganCampbell I added an example

Comment: @LoganCampbell do you want to go to page `portraits` on the same site if I type portraits?

Comment: I see your code. You have too many `/` after the URL

Answer (score 0):

```js
function goToSubUrl() {
  window.location.href = "https://www.example.com/" + document.getElementById("suburl").value.trim();
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="suburl"></input>
<br>
<button onclick="goToSubUrl()">Go to page</button>
```

Comment: thanks this one is showing the top part in clear text on the site and when entered for some reason the button does not do anything

Comment: Try it outside of this snippet environment. :D

Comment: sorry this is my first attempt at this haha from where in the code do i start copying :)

Answer (score 0):

This changes the origin from where it was loaded to what you put as the input

```html
<form id="urlForm" onsubmit="location.href=location.origin+'/'+this.url.value">
<input type="text" name="url" value="" />
</form>
```

Comment: How is this different from our answers other than using inline event handling which is not recommended?

Comment: because it's JUST html?

Comment: Well it isn't, but yeah - not recommended but yeah

Comment: It seems that you actually have a version that OP could use better since he did not grasp that the JavaScript lives in script tags

Comment: `location.origin` is possibly not what OP wanted though

Comment: true, you can replace that with `"someRandomOrigin"`